# catkin_make , python-catkin-pkg doesn't work,

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, catkin

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
hwlee@hwlee:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make

Command 'catkin_make' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install catkin
```

---

```
hwlee@hwlee:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt install catkin

Reading package lists... Done

Building dependency tree       

Reading state information... Done

Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:


The following packages have unmet dependencies:


 catkin : Depends: python-catkin-pkg but it is not going to be installed

E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

```
hwlee@hwlee:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt-get install python-catkin-pkg

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-catkin-pkg is already the newest version (0.4.15-100).

0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I installed ros-melodic to new computer and have this problem.

How can I solve this one?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/341758/catkin_make-,-python-catkin-pkg-doesn%27t-work,/) by [hwlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/50917/hwlee/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-01-15

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> hwlee@hwlee:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
> ```

```
Command 'catkin_make' not found
```

Have you remembered to `source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash` before trying to run `catkin_make`?

As to this:

> ```
> hwlee@hwlee:~/catkin_ws$ sudo apt install catkin
> ```

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
```

> ```
> Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable distribution that some required packages have not yet been created or been moved out of Incoming.
> ```

This is caused by mixing official packages (ie: distributed via `packages.ros.org`) with [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages).

Catkin for ROS Melodic would be `ros-melodic-catkin`, not `catkin`.

You cannot mix these two package sources.

Please read [UpstreamPackages](http://wiki.ros.org/UpstreamPackages) and install `ros-melodic-catkin` (but you most likely already have it installed).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-01-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hwlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/50917/hwlee/) on 2020-01-15**:
Omg, you solve this problem perfectly. Thank you so much!!!!
I used ros-kinetic so that I was confused :(
I did two things you said, and I got saved!

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-01-15**:\

> I used ros-kinetic

Did you tag this question with `melodic` by accident?

**Comment by [hwlee](https://answers.ros.org/users/50917/hwlee/) on 2020-01-15**:
Ah, I meant I used ros-kinetic before. I'm using melodic now :)

**Comment by [Solrac3589](https://answers.ros.org/users/31684/solrac3589/) on 2020-01-15**:
For what I saw it seems to me to be more related with the missing source. If you have the same error again, add the command gvdhoorn told you inside .bashrc file (at the end)